# Wso2 bam 2.3.0 ERROR ExecDriver "No such file or directory"

Tags: hadoop, wso2, wso2-bam

I've installed Wso2 bam 2.3.0 and started Analytics.
I completed all the steps from ["Introduction to BAM Analytics Framework"](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM220/Introduction+to+BAM+Analytics+Framework)
My system Windows 7 64bit.
I've installed cygwin with packages base, net, security and  updated my PATH variable by appending `;C:\cygwin\bin`

After "execute" in the console,  errors show up. Note that the file exists:

```
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-06-18 10:31:35,383] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Job Submission failed with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException(chmod: getting attributes of `C:\\wso2\\wso2bam\\tmp\\hadoop\\staging\\gbelyaev-911074626\\.staging': No such file or directory
)'
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: chmod: getting attributes of `C:\\wso2\\wso2bam\\tmp\\hadoop\\staging\\gbelyaev-911074626\\.staging': No such file or directory

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.execCommand(RawLocalFileSystem.java:553)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.execSetPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:798)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:792)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.main(ExecDriver.java:728)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
 {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-06-18 10:31:35,383] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Job Submission failed with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException(chmod: getting attributes of `C:\\wso2\\wso2bam\\tmp\\hadoop\\staging\\gbelyaev-911074626\\.staging': No such file or directory
)'
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: chmod: getting attributes of `C:\\wso2\\wso2bam\\tmp\\hadoop\\staging\\gbelyaev-911074626\\.staging': No such file or directory

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.execCommand(RawLocalFileSystem.java:553)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.execSetPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:798)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:792)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.main(ExecDriver.java:728)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
 {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-06-18 10:31:37,903] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  Execution failed with exit status: 2 {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-06-18 10:31:37,903] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  Execution failed with exit status: 2 {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-06-18 10:31:37,907] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  Obtaining error information {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-06-18 10:31:37,907] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  Obtaining error information {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-06-18 10:31:37,915] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  
Task failed!
```

Comment: After reboot windows it worked fine

Comment: @Docteur - please don't flood the suggested edit queue with burnination tag change edits. If you read towards the bottom of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate, the guidelines say that you should sit out burnination until you have full edit privileges, because it isn't a good use of reviewer time to make three people manually approve every single tag change.

Comment: @sphanley Okay, thanks for the advice. :-) I should have read more closely!

Comment: @Docteur no worries! The enthusiasm for contributing is appreciated, it's just not the optimal way to help out before you've got edit privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reboot windows it worked fine